# Remover espaço em branco de ion-item

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho uma lista de itens buscados dinamicamente do banco de dados

```
 <ion-list *ngFor="let associado of associados" class="card-pessoa" no-padding>  
<ion-item no-padding class="card-pessoa">
 <ion-thumbnail item-start class="pessoa"> 
 <img src="assets/imgs/pessoa.png"> 
 </ion-thumbnail>
 <div class="nome-associado">{{associado.nom_associado}}</div>   
 <div class="cargo-empresa">{{associado.cargo_empresa}}</div>   
 <div class="nome-fantasia">{{associado.nom_fantasia}}</div>    
 <div class="cargo-comite">{{associado.cargo_comite}}</div>    
</ion-item>
```

Gostaria de saber como remover esse espaço branco entre os itens da lista. Pesquisei mas sem resultados, então resolvi pedir ajuda aqui :)

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altere o `*ngFor` para o `<ion-item>`. Está no `<ion-list>`.

```
<ion-list class="card-pessoa" no-padding>  
    <ion-item *ngFor="let associado of associados" no-padding class="card-pessoa">
        <ion-thumbnail item-start class="pessoa"> 
            <img src="assets/imgs/pessoa.png"> 
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <div class="nome-associado">{{associado.nom_associado}}</div>   
        <div class="cargo-empresa">{{associado.cargo_empresa}}</div>   
        <div class="nome-fantasia">{{associado.nom_fantasia}}</div>    
        <div class="cargo-comite">{{associado.cargo_comite}}</div>    
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```